# If BD + BC = 3BE, how can we prove G is the centroid of triangle ABC?

Tags: geometry, triangles, centroid

In the acute-angled triangle $\triangle ABC$, we mark the middle with $M$ side $BC$ and with $D$ the foot of the height in $A$. Let $G$ be a point on the median $AM$ and $E$ is its projection on the $MD$ segment. If $BD + BC = 3BE$, prove that $G$ is the centroid of $\triangle ABC$..

Okey. You can see below the drawing and the ideas I had... I thought of the formula for the median. And then show that $MG$ is $1/3$ of $AM$ or $AG$ is $2/3$ of $AM$.
Another idea was to put $BG$ intersect $AC$ in point $N$. And then show that $N$ is half of $AC$.
Anyways, I don't know which idea is the right one and with which one to start and where to start.
Any ideas are welcome!

[image: A triangle with BD + BC = 3BE]

Answer (score 1):

You would like to "show that $MG$ is $1/3$ of $AM$", which will imply $G$ is the centroid as $AM$ is an median. This is the right approach.
[image]
Since $GE\parallel AD$, it is enough to show that $ME$ is $1/3$ of $MD$. Now all given conditions and our goal are on the segment $BC$.

Consider the equality $BD +BC = 3BE$. While segment $BM$ is shared among $BD, BC$ and $BE$, it appear neither in $ME$ nor in $MD$. Let us try eliminating it from that equality, using the condition $BC = 2BM$.

$$\begin{aligned}
BD +BC &= (BM+MD)+ 2BM \\
3BE&= 3(BM+ME)
\end{aligned}$$

The difference of the two equalities above is $0=3ME-MD$, which is what we want.

Comment: Nice answer .....+1

Comment: Heyy! Thank you soooo much  for the answer! But, I don't really understand the last paragraph How did you demonstrate that BN is a midline?? Thank you from the bottom of my heart!

Comment: Its okey. I understand it! Thank you, again!!!

Comment: @Apass.Jack How did you arrived at the fact that NK is a midsegment?? BG intersect AC in point N, we don't know that N is the mid point of AC

Comment: ?????????????????????

Comment: Thank you soo much!!!!

Comment: Thanks to lonela and Matei for noticing my error. Sorry that I was misled by my wild imagination. I just posted a correct answer.

Comment: No problem! I would never thought of the idea! Thanks once again!

Comment: @MateiTrandafir Would you mind re-accepting my answer?